# Example of a homeomorphism of a plane which fixes unit circle point wise

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

What would a non trivial example of a homeomorphism of a plane which fixes unit circle point wise. If I take 
\begin{equation}
h(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x,y)& \text{$(x,y)\in S^1$}\\
(x+2,y+2) & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is this a homeomorphism?

Comment: It's not continuous.

Comment: Yes Right!! I am not able to think of such homeomorphisms, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How about defining a suitable function $g:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^+$ which is constant on circles centred at the origin and consider $f(x,y)=g(x,y)(x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, Thank you !

Comment: Take the flow of a bounded smooth vector field that vanishes on the circle.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown.   Such a g would be the identity map so f(x,y) = (x,y)(x,y) whatever that means.

Comment: @YCor, how exactly?

Comment: @WilliamElliot no. His example $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2+y^2)^{-1/4}(x,y)$ works.